# Ubuntu Giant Lag Spikes :(

Tags: usb, mouse

Hello I recently switched to Ubuntu and I play many games but every time I press a key from 1 to = it lags so much and my mouse has buttons on the side that use those numbers and im not able to play games anymore because its just so laggy and stuttery :( (EDIT) it only lags when i press the buttons on the mouse which is weird.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release? What software? How kuch RAM/Swap? `free` will show.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]